# LEFT JOIN two tables through a third table

Tags: sql, database, select, join, left-join

How do I `LEFT JOIN` tables A and B if they can only be connected through a table C?
So the table C includes a linking attribute that connects it with the table A and **another** attribute that connects it with the table B.

Comment: Just do *two* joins: A -> C -> B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE Base base
LEFT JOIN A a ON a.a = base.a
LEFT JOIN C c ON c.c = a.c
LEFT JOIN B b ON b.b = c.b
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use two `left join`s:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM   a
LEFT JOIN c ON a.id = c.a_id
LEFT JOIN b ON b.id = c.b_id
```